# Extract numbers from a string-Javascript

Tags: javascript, strings, array

Consider the following string in javascript:

```
var string="border-radius:90px 20px 30px 40px";
```

I want to extract the 4 numbers from that string and store them in an array called numbers.To do that I developed the following code:

```
var numbers=string.split("border-radius:");
numbers=numbers[1].split("px");
```

This code is working fine but I was wondering if there is a better approach/solution.Any ideas are welcomed

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I used the following regexp to extract numbers from a string:

```
var string = "border-radius:10px 20px 30px 40px";
var numbers = string.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
```

Comment: This is a much better & more robust solution. I'm sure others can help you make your regex better (not my strength so I'm not commenting on that aspect).

Comment: If you then want the numbers to be actual numbers instead of strings, you can then `map` it; the simplest version of this would be: `string.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)`

Comment: To handle negative numbers (e.g. s = 'translate(57px, -113px)'):

var numbers = s.match(/-?\d+/g).map(Number);

Comment: This method omits the presiding / leading zeros, example "order id # 00123" will result in extracting 123 but not 00123

Answer (score 13):

The code will fail in below cases:

1. Negative numbers
2. Decimal numbers
3. Units other than `px`(e.g. `pt`, `%`, `vw`, `vh`, ...)

Moreover, the `numbers` array contains space before numbers and an empty string at the end which is not required.

---

I recommend to use below regex to extract numbers from strings

```
/[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g
```

1. `[+-]?`: Optional `+` or `-` sign before number
2. `\d+`: Match one or more numbers
3. `(?:\.\d+)?`: Optional decimal point. `?:` denotes non-capturing group.
4. `g` flag: To get all matches

After the numbers are extracted from string, they can be converted to Number format.

```js
var regex = /[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g;

var str = `padding: 0;
font-size: 16pt;
width: 50%;
height: 20vh;
margin-right: 12px;
padding-right: -12.5px;`;

var match;
while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
  console.log(match[0]);
}
```

Here's online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LHJIQz/1) of the regex on Regex101.